# IIS 8.5: Change authentification mode for url sub path

Tags: authentication, iis, windows-authentication, iis-8.5

We have a client intranet web application running as a remote proxy on IIS 8.5 with Windows Authentication enabled. Now, we need to disable *Windows Authentication* and enable *Anonymous Authentication* on the URL sub path `/api/` to make all data from this path publicly availailbe within the client intranet domain.

Actually, the solution from **chensformers** ([Add authentication to subfolders without creating a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508950/add-authentication-to-subfolders-without-creating-a-web-application#answer-5385271)) sounds quite promising. However didn't get it to run yet as I am missing a *section declaration*.

How to configure IIS 8.5 to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long trying, I found the answer myself. The answer is two-parted:

1. The answer of @Tim Lewis ([Allow anonymous authentication for a single folder in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config/11434739#11434739)) led me to the right configuration. In the file `applicationHost.config` in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`, I changed the following lines from `Deny` to `Allow`:

   ```
   <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
   <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
   <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
   ```

   Then inside the `web.config` from `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, I inserted the following lines before the last `</configuration>` tag:

   ```
   <location path="api">
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <allow users="*" />
       </authorization>
     </system.web>
     <system.webServer>
       <security>
         <authentication>
           <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
         </authentication>
       </security>
     </system.webServer>
   </location>
   ```

   After restarting *IIS Manager* and the server, the windows authentication from the main domain should be overwritten for the sub path (`/api` in my case) and every URL inside the sub path should be publicly available.
2. However, if this configuration doesn't work at first, it could be that   your editor of choice (in my case **Notepad++**) does not open the correct content of `appplictionHost.config` (for whatever reason) and all changes in it don't take effect at all (also see @MeanGreen [Applicationhost.config not showing changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641621/applicationhost-config-not-showing-changes)).

   I solved it by installing and using **Notepad2 x64** (http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html). After this, the above changes took effect and worked immediately.

PS: see also http://forums.iis.net/t/1233382.aspx?IIS+8+5+Change+authentification+mode+for+url+sub+path for a longer discussion of this topic.

Comment: Regarding (2): 32-bit apps and 64-bit apps see different versions of `C:\Windows\System32`, under which `applicationHost.config`is located. Therefore, always open this file with a 64-bit app. Using regular Notepad or any x64 text editor should work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert **api** folder into application i.e. **right click the folder => convert to application**. Once it is converted to application in the central pane double click **Authentication => Select Anonymous Authentication** and enable it. Disable all other authentication modes.

P.S. - You can try without converting into an app. I haven't tested so not sure if it works just as a folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no physical `api` folder as this is just an url path within the (Django) web application where the reverse proxy (URL Rewrite module) points to.

If I set the physical path of the application to the same path as the main path (`c:\inetpub\wwwroot`) I get the following **Internal Server Error**:
`Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.appcache'`

Which is the right path to set?

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers.

This Question/Answer helped me a ton! I too am working with a virtual path except it is from a python flask application. Except I have an admin site that I wanted behind `windowsauthentication` the rest of the site is `anonymousAuthentication` .

For me this worked:

1. Allow delegation of **both** windows and anonymous authentication modules following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12343141/7838574
2. Updating the `web.config`

```xml
<configuration>
    <!-- ...the beginning of the web.config file as is... -->
    </appSettings>
    <location path="admin">  <!-- relative to where the web.config file is located -->
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <authentication>
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          </authentication>
        </security>
      </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I did not have to restart IIS Manager or the server.