# Accessing IIS Windows Authentication Website from Excel Web Data

Tags: django, excel, iis

I have a basic website written in Python Django, hosted on IIS 8.5.  The website is used in the company intranet with Windows Authentication.

Accessing the website through a browser gives no problems for authentication.  However, making use of a simple web API to retrieve data for reporting purposes is giving problems.

I'm trying to load a URL into Excel which supplies data in CSV format (Data -> From Web).  Disabling IIS Windows Authentication and using Anonymous works perfectly.  However, enabling Windows Authentication does not work as Excel says 'credentials are incorrect'.

The URL response is a simple HttpResponse object with CSV data.  Nothing weird or complicated happening.

Any idea where to troubleshoot this?  My IIS knowledge is limited in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the API part of the website to anonymous authentication as per this answer.  it did the trick for me:

[IIS 8.5: Change authentification mode for url sub path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39043015/iis-8-5-change-authentification-mode-for-url-sub-path)